# If $A^{1/2}$ is the square-root defined in terms of the spectral decomposition, are we able to show that $\mathcal D(A^{1/2})\supseteq\mathcal D(A)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, $A$ be a densely-defined nonnegative self-adjoint linear operator on $H$, $(\pi_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\mathbb R}$ denote the spectral family on $H$ corresponding to $A$, $$\varrho_x(\lambda):=\langle\pi_\lambda x,x\rangle_H=\left\|\pi_\lambda x\right\|_H^2\;\;\;\text{for }\lambda\in\mathbb R$$ and $$u(\lambda):=\left.\begin{cases}0&\text{, if }\lambda\le0\\\sqrt\lambda&\text{, if }\lambda\ge0\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }\lambda\in\mathbb R.$$ Now let $$u(A)x:=\int u(\lambda)\:{\rm d}\pi_\lambda x\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathcal D(u(A)):=\left\{x\in H:u\in L^2(\varrho_x)\right\}.$$

> Are we able to show $\mathcal D(u(A))\supseteq\mathcal D(A)$ and $Ax=u(A)u(A)x$ for all $x\in\mathcal D(A)$?

By definition, $x\in\mathcal D(u(A))$ if and only if $$\int_{[0,\:\infty)}\lambda\:\varrho_x({\rm d}\lambda)<\infty\tag1,$$ but I don't know why $(1)$ is satisfied by each $x\in\mathcal D(A)$.

Comment: You may wish to read about the functional calculus for self-adjoint operators, which basically answers every question of this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral theorem gives
$$
    x\in\mathcal{D}(A) \iff \int \lambda^2 d\rho_x(\lambda) < \infty.
$$
In that case, $\|Ax\|^2=\int\lambda^2 d\rho_x(\lambda)$. Likewise, if $\sqrt{A}$ is the unique positive square root of $A \ge 0$, then
$$
     x\in\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{A})\iff \int \lambda d\rho_x(\lambda) < \infty.
$$
In that case, $\|\sqrt{A}x\|^2=\int \lambda d\rho_x(\lambda)$. Both integrals converge on any finite interval, including $[0,1]$. And the second one converges on $[1,\infty)$ if the first does because $\lambda \le \lambda^2$ on $[1,\infty)$. So $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)\implies x\in\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{A})$.

Comment: (a) Each $\rho_x$ is a *finite* measure, right? (b) If the answer to (a) is *yes*, then doesn't $\mathcal D(A)\subseteq\mathcal D(\sqrt A)$ follow from Jensen's inequality for the concave function $[0,\infty)\ni\lambda\mapsto\sqrt\lambda$ as well? (c) Can we infer anything about the shape of the (vector) measures $\pi_\lambda$ when we know the concrete shape of the operator $A$ (as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3374383/47771))?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : Yes, $\rho_x$ is a finite measure with $\rho_x(\mathbb{R})=\|x\|^2$. That's why my simple explanation is sufficient. But you can substitute any argument you want.